# Decimal number and Charts Module

Tags: 7, views, charts

I installed Charts with Google Charts in Drupal 7. Everything is ok, but when I have to use decimal numbers, with number 0.5 or 0.8, it appears to me .0 or .8 both on the vertical axis of my column chart and on the graph itself. Why?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your field settings for the decimal field?

Comment: I also recommend making a duplicate of the display and then converting to a table to make sure the decimal field is showing up properly in that display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

last night I'v found the problem and solve.

change the row in the file "charts_google.inc" row n. 223

from
       $format = $prefix . '#' . $decimal_count . $suffix;

to

```
  $format = $prefix . '#0' . $decimal_count . $suffix;
```

[image]

[image]